# Getting string from SharedPreferences in AsyncTask, java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to get a string saved in SharedPreferences in AsyncTask, but unfortunately I get the following error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

Here's the relevant code:

```
public class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private Context context;
    String deviceId;

    private AsyncInterface asyncInterface;

    public FetchData(AsyncInterface asyncInterface) {
        this.context = context;
        this.asyncInterface = asyncInterface;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("deviceId", MODE_PRIVATE); //Error here
        deviceId = sharedPreferences.getString("deviceId", deviceId);

    }
}
```

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should add a constructor parameter `Context context`.

Comment: Thank you so much. That fixed my problem !